# How to replace all elements in vector by the sum of element digits?

Tags: c++, vector

I have trouble understanding how to replace all elements in vector by the sum of element digits. For example if i have sequence of such digits `9 22 54 981` my output has to be `9 4 9 18`.I know how to count the sum. I have this vector called `file_numbers` .But I am stuck at this point. Thanks for the help.

```
   int SumOfDigits(int digit)
{

    int sum = 0;
    while (digit > 0)
    {
        sum += digit % 10;
        digit /= 10;
    }
    return sum;
}
void FourthTask(vector<int>& file_numbers)
{
    std::transform(file_numbers.begin(),
        file_numbers.end(),
        file_numbers.begin(),SumOfDigits);
}
```

Comment: "_how to replace all elements in vector by the sum of element digits_" Hint: you aren't doing any replacing once you counted the sum (in addition to not resetting the value of `sum` to 0, before moving to counting the sum of digits of another number). Edit: `for (size_t i = 1;` the indices of `std::vector` start at 0, so you'll miss the first number.

Comment: split the problem in 2 parts: computing sum from digit (54 -> 9), and transforming each values of vector.

Comment: Im just creating a new vector?

Comment: @Jarod42 that is just how I am trying to do this task. I just dont understand how to transform those values

Comment: Forget about vector for a moment.  You should really write a simple function that takes an int and returns the sum of the digits.  Once you have that, then just call that function with each of the vector's entries in a loop.

Comment: *I just dont understand how to transform* -- well, your statement has the answer, `std::transform`.  `std::transform(file_numbers.begin(), file_numbers.end(), file_numbers.begin(), ...);`  you just need to fill in what `...` is, and that is function I mentioned earlier.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie can you please explain this part " then just call that function with each of the vector's entries in a loop." I added this function you told

Comment: Please update your post with this function.  The function you have now does not do that.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie done

Comment: So now you have that, just use `std::transform` as I mentioned earlier.  Just put the name of that function in the last argument of `std::transform`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie there is mistake in this line ` std::transform(file_numbers.begin(), file_numbers.end(), changed_file_numbers.begin(), SumOfDigits());`

Comment: First, your function is supposed to take an integer as an argument.  Instead you declared `digit` as a local variable.  Second, `std::transform` is declared in the `<algorithm>` header.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thank you so much! It works!

Comment: @TerRini -- If this is a homework assignment, I highly suggest you read what [std::transform](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) does.  Basically it takes that sequence of values, and applies a "transformation" to each of the values in the sequence.  That transformation being taking that value and getting its sum of digits.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie oh, I see. Thanks again, It is probably the first time someone explained me code so qualitatively. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might need to `#include <algorithm>`

```
int SumOfDigits(int digit)
{
    int sum = 0;
    while (digit > 0)
    {
        sum += digit % 10;
        digit /= 10;
    }
    return sum;
}

void FourthTask(vector<int>& file_numbers)
{
    std::transform(file_numbers.begin(), 
                   file_numbers.end(),
                   file_numbers.begin(),
                   SumOfDigits);
}
```

Comment: Also, `SumOfDigits` should be declared, since it occurs after the `FourthTask` function.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie True. I moved it :)

Answer (score 0):

Code first, then notes:

```
void SumTask(std::vector<int>& file_numbers){
    for (auto& i :  file_numbers){
        int sum = 0;
            while (i > 0){
                sum += i % 10;
                i /= 10;
            }
            i = sum;
    }
}
```

Notes:

- Sum goes **inside** the for loop, otherwise you're going to sum all the digits previously processed as well
- Use a range-loop, they're pretty well optimized

Answer (score -2):

Convert the element to string, then loop for each character, convert character to int and add it up to previous character's sum..

Comment: Why do you need to convert the `int` to a `string`, if you can loop through digits of it anyways (the logic for it is in the question itself)? Such conversion is pointless.

Comment: *Convert the element to string*  -- No.  Extracting each digit from an `int` does not require coverting an int to a string.

Comment: How do you extract a single digit from a int without converting it to a string?

Comment: @MerakMarey -- Use division and modulus.  Work it out on paper using these techniques.

Comment: @MerakMarey -- *It;s cheaper and clearer the conversion*  -- If you're talking about converting to a string, it is not "cheaper" by any means.  String conversion is more expensive than simply doing integer arithmetic.

Comment: @MerakMarey -- The OP is clearly using `int` as the type, not some arbitrary length string of digits.

Comment: 32767  32766  32765 32,764 ...better?

Comment: At the end, the conversion to string is only once per vector element..do you still think is cheaper to use math?

Comment: You are not considering what goes into converting to a string.  It is much more than a one or two line assembly operation.  In contrast, integer math on native `int`'s is faster, since that *is* something that takes one or two assembly instructions to perform.  Bottom line -- strings are slower to process than `int's`.  And just a warning -- if you go on an interview, and you gave the "convert to a string" as a way of doing this, you'll be in trouble.

Comment: @Merak Marey "How do you extract a single digit from a int without converting it to a string?" - maths.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You are focusing only on the performance side of the equation, not in maintainability or readability..For sure, doing it with math will give you those 30 milliseconds on 3 billions elements vectors, but I didn't see the "critical process" flag of the OP anywhere...been doing this for 30 years and believe me...clients don't want you to spend an hour for the "creme de la creme" solution..they need a solution for yesterday.. That way of thinking gave me this result...I don't do interviews anymore..:)

Comment: @JesperJuhl.. There is always multiple ways of doing things...seeing only one makes you monolithic, and eventually, useless...:)

Comment: @MerakMarey [Timing results](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e0242755d80f5c89).  Take it for what it's worth.  Also, those milliseconds could mean the difference between a financial win or loss.